# Can't scope to my table adapter in designer code

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

in the form designer, I'm getting an error like:
 Me.DayListTableAdapter = New ProgName.aaDataSetTableAdapters.aaTableAdapter()

saying it's not defined.

If I change it to:

Me.DayListTableAdapter = New Global.ProgName.aaDataSetTableAdapters.aaTableAdapter()

Then it compiles fine.  Everytime I change the Datasources, I have to go back and re-edit the designer code.

Its a project that I started as a sub-project, class library and and adapting to 'Windows forms Application' as a main project.

Am I just missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: the fact that the designer files all have a waning `Do not modify it using the code editor.` should tell you that you are going at it the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix mentioned, the designer (especially dataset designer) is the wrong place to fix your code.
sometimes I count to 10 just open it :)

You may try to delete the table adapter from the dataset, and add it again. If that did not solve your problem then I guess your dataset is missed up.

Did you add this dataset to your project but its originally created in another project? or you create this dataset in the current project?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your custom data adapter (aaDataSetTableAdapters.aaTableAdapter) to be available during design time, I would recommend creating a custom control that inherits from or implements a data adapter and adding it to the Toolbox.